# is there a sage equivalent to php 'implode' for a list?

Tags: python, syntax, sage

I would like to take a list such as

`L = [1,2,3,4]`

and output a string such as

`string = L.join('::')`
to output 
`1::2::3::4`

i can easily run a loop such as

`string='';`

`for a in L:
    string = string+'::'+str(a)`

but i would like to do it all in one line as i am passing this command to a php script which runs exec command and it seems to break with the linebreaks and indentations thus.. i would like to write it in one line or figure out how to pass it as a php variable to do shell execute
thx

Comment: *i am passing this command to a php script which runs exec command* this sounds like a terrible idea - there are huge oportunities for someone to abuse something like that.

Comment: thank you @Lattyware, I appreciate your help, that is exactly what I needed. but Can you elaborate just tiny bit on the perils of this idea please.  just to clarify this is not a php script available for endusers to modify.

Comment: If you are passing in something you are then using `exec` on, they don't need to edit it, they can just put an expression that does something malicious into the string somehow, and suddenly they can execute arbitrary code. This kind of injection is a really common attack vector - there are always better ways of doing things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somthing like this

```
'::'.join(map(str,L))
```

or insted of map

```
'::'.join(str(i) for i in L)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> "::".join(str(x) for x in [1, 2, 3, 4])
1::2::3::4
```

As `str.join()` requires strings, here I use a [generator expression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to create strings from the numbers in the original list.

The method exists on the string, mirroring the `str.split()` method. It also means that it works with arbitrary iterables, not just lists.